# Unable to Post image in Android using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, image

I am trying to post a status and image via Android Face book SDK.
Though i am able to login and post status but not the image.
Here is my code , the image. Event listener Does the job of posting image, But nothing happens when i click it after logging in.

```
package digitaljalebisharefb.digitaljalebishare.fbshare;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView;
import com.facebook.share.model.ShareLinkContent;
import com.facebook.share.model.SharePhoto;
import com.facebook.share.model.SharePhotoContent;
import com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    LoginManager loginManager;
    Button share,details,image;
    ShareDialog shareDialog;
    LoginButton login;
    ProfilePictureView profile;
    Dialog details_dialog;
    TextView details_txt;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();



        login = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        profile = (ProfilePictureView)findViewById(R.id.picture);
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share);
        image = (Button)findViewById(R.id.image);
        details = (Button)findViewById(R.id.details);
        login.setReadPermissions("public_profile email");
        share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        details.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        details_dialog = new Dialog(this);
        details_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_details);
        details_dialog.setTitle("Details");
        details_txt = (TextView)details_dialog.findViewById(R.id.details);

        details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                details_dialog.show();
            }
        });


        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
            RequestData();
            share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view){
                if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {

                              public void onClick (View view){
            if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {

                                   Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fb);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();


                Set<String> permissions = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions();
                AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

                Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
                postParams.putString("message", "naval");
                postParams. putByteArray ("source", byteArray);

                GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(accessToken, "me/photos", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, null);
                GraphRequestAsyncTask asynTaskGraphRequest = new GraphRequestAsyncTask (request);
                asynTaskGraphRequest.execute();
                // URL image - code 2 - URL images
               /* ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentTitle("Hey")
                        .setContentDescription("Yepiiiiiiiii")
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://p.imgci.com/db/PICTURES/CMS/128400/128483.1.jpg"))
                        .build();*/
             //   shareDialog.show(content);
            }

        }
                }

            }

        });
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                    share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    details.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    profile.setProfileId(null);
                }
            }
        });
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().build();
                shareDialog.show(content);


            }
        });
        login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
                    RequestData();
                    share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            }
        });

    }
    public void RequestData(){
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

                JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                try {
                    if(json != null){
                        String text = "<b>Name :</b> "+json.getString("name")+"<br><br><b>Email :</b> "+json.getString("email")+"<br><br><b>Profile link :</b> "+json.getString("link");
                        details_txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
                        profile.setProfileId(json.getString("id"));
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }




    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the AsyncRunner class to post and Image/Photo on Facebook.

```
public void publishPhoto(byte[] imgData, string message) {

AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner (facebook);

Bundle parameters = new Bundle ();
parameters.putString (Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
parameters.putString ("message", message);
parameters.putByteArray ("source", imgData);

mAsyncRunner.Request ("me/photos", parameters, "POST", new RequestListener (), null);
}
```

Call this method inside onClick of sharephoto.

**Update 1**

From latest SDK use [`GraphRequestAsyncTask`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/GraphRequestAsyncTask/)

```
   Set<String> permissions = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions();
   AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

   Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
   postParams.putString("message", msg);
   postParams. putByteArray ("source", imgData);

   GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(accessToken, "me/photos", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, null);
   GraphRequestAsyncTask asynTaskGraphRequest = new GraphRequestAsyncTask (request);
   asynTaskGraphRequest.execute();
```

P.S Assuming you have all the required permission to do so.

Comment: AsyncFacebookRunner  & Facebook seems deprecated , right??

Comment: which SDK function you are using ?

Comment: You can also use `GraphRequestAsyncTask`, which is available in the latest sdk

Comment: thanks i was able to post, i have following query : 1. i am able to post link images 2. but local images shows authorization - does i have to submit for review? 3. can i directly post status from a text string?

Comment: Didn't get that.  Come again

Comment: Ok , i have updated the code above for  "  image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() " - you can have a look 1. code 1  is for posting local images - that does not work 2. code -2 is via URL that works but cannot add captions. My question is do i have to get my app reviewed by FB to get Local images posting works?

Comment: You are using a sharephoto api,  not the one I suggested.

Comment: ok , i am trying ur code , the "  GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(accessToken, "me/photos"," here me/photos means absolute local path?

Comment: Me/photos is the facebook path for uploading photos

Comment: ok so tell me do i need publish _ permissions for this? as i have not forwaded my application for review? and will it post image with discription? I tried but that dint worked.Updated the code above

Comment: Here it is : 11-01 19:03:39.102 4300-4329/digitaljalebisharefb.digitaljalebishare.fbshare E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4052fc0

Comment: I dont think this is the issue.

Comment: it is necessary to be registered as an **authorized developer** at the app settings in the developer facebook web.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I found:

If you want to publish an image on the wall that you need to do that before login :

```
private static List<String> PERMISSIONS = 

    Arrays.asList("public_profile","user_photos","user_videos", "email","user_likes","user_posts",
                                                    "user_hometown", "user_location","user_about_me","user_birthday",
                                                    "user_friends","user_relationship_details");
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this,Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // App code
                        Log.i(TAG,"onSuccess registerCallback");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                        Log.i(TAG,"onCancel registerCallback");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                        Log.i(TAG,"onError registerCallback");
                    }
         });
```

Then you need to call this method :

```
/**
     * This is a method which can post an image to the facebook wall.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void sharePhoto() throws IOException {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.gift_icon;
                                /*OR*/
        Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://dxswifi_direct.com.wifidirectcommunication/" + R.drawable.gift_icon);
        Uri otherPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://dxswifi_direct.com.wifidirectcommunication/drawable/gift_icon");
        String path1 = path.toString();
        String path2 = otherPath.toString();

        imageUri = "http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/04/22/21/27DEB82000000578-3051045-image-a-25_1429735533586.jpg";
        URL url = new URL(imageUri);
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        /*SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image).build();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUri, bmOptions);*/
        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image).build();
        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(photo).build();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.facebook_uploading), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ShareApi.share(content, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.facebook_successful), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel()
            {
                Log.v("FACEBOOK_TEST", "share api cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e)
            {
                Log.v("FACEBOOK_TEST", "share api error " + e);
            }
        });
    }
```